# Как написать из другого класса в textbox формы ? или как делать правильно?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня в конце работы одного из методов класса `Other.cs` - формируется коллекция - данные которой я хотел бы распотрошить в `textBox`. Т.е. вытаскивать поштучно из коллекции и вставлять в `textBox` формы. Если подробнее, это коллекция `HtmlNodeCollection` от библиотеки `HtmlAgilityPack`

**Вопрос**: был бы просто 1 `string` - то не проблема передать в `return ""`, а вот как распотрошить коллекцию ?

Не могу же я в классе `Form1` сразу принять так много `string`

А прям к `textBox` не удаётся получить доступ из другой класса.

Передавать целиком эту коллекцию и внутри `Form1` потрошить ?

Answer (score 2):

Вы без проблем можете вернуть как и троку так и коллекцию.
Если коллекция не большая и таких обращений не много, её можно перебрать в основном потоке. Если же коллекция внушительная и её перебор может занять время - выполнять действия стоит в отдельном потоке. Лучше для этого использовать асинхронные методы.

**UPDATE:**

Для передачи данных во время выполнения итераций можно использовать события ([MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event)).
В классе определяете событие, на которое другие объекты смогут подписываться на него и получать данные. Ниже приведен код с примером

Так выглядит тестовый класс:

```
 public class Other
{
    public event EventHandler<IReadOnlyList<string>> ReceiveCollection;

    public void StartBuildCollection()
    {
        // временный лист
        List<string> tmp = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // добавляем элемент в лист
            tmp.Add("this is string # " + i.ToString() + " - 1");
            tmp.Add("this is string # " + i.ToString() + " - 2");
            tmp.Add("this is string # " + i.ToString() + " - 3");

            //Передаем часть коллекции через событие
            ReceiveCollection?.Invoke(this, tmp.AsReadOnly());
            tmp.Clear();
            // Эмитируем зарежку выполнения
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

И собственно сама реализация перебора:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // создаем класс из которого получаем колекцию
    Other test = new Other();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // подписка на событие класса, через которое будем получать часть коллекции
        test.ReceiveCollection += Test_ReceiveCollection;
    }

    private void Test_ReceiveCollection(object sender, IReadOnlyList<string> e)
    {
        foreach(var item in e.ToArray())
        {
            ThreadSafeInvoke(() =>
            {
                textBox1.Text += item + Environment.NewLine;
            });
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // очищаем текстовое поле
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        // Запуск создания колекции
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            test.StartBuildCollection();
        });
    }

    public void ThreadSafeInvoke(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                // Execute action.
                action();
                // Get out.
                return;
            }
            // Marshal to the required context.
            //this.Invoke(action, Array.Empty<object>());
            this.Invoke(action, new object[0]);
        }
        catch { }
        // If the invoke is not required, then invoke here and get out.            
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Примерно так я и делаю(, но там долгоё пополнение коллекции - много циклов - вот как бы по факту 1 итерации часть  коллекции из класса передавать.
Если бы сразу в textBox можно было - прям сразу из того же метода класса - был бы выход, вот не могу сообразить(

Comment: Тогда вам стоит использовать события, это позволит возвращать из класса часть коллекции каждую итерацию. Я обновил код в соответствии с вашей задачей. Проверьте это решение